# How to eliminate Blazor screen fade?

Tags: blazor-server-side, fade

I've developed a Blazor Server application. When I run it in IIS Express on my laptop or on IIS hosted by AWS, the same thing happens - every minute or so the screen fades for a few seconds and the app becomes unresponsive. It then recovers, allowing the user to carry on with what they were doing.

This problem is code agnostic - it happens regardless of whatever code I use. The questions asked in Stack Overflow view screen fade as something desirable they are wanting to achieve. In my case, it is something undesirable I would like to get rid of.

Here is a video that describes my problem: https://clipchamp.com/watch/U0YEXCpp7Ha

Comment: Check the browser dev tools for messages - that looks like it re-connecting to the server. The messages in dev tools console may help.

Comment: Yes, that's the reconnecting mechanism kicking in. It's a known problem with Blazor Server. How and if that happens depends on quality of connection between the server and host, as well as SignalR transport parameters.

Comment: @MisterMagoo, that was very helpful. 
Here is a snapshot of what I observed: https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket.creme/Downloads/Blazor+230405A.png

Comment: @maciek, even though it is a known problem, I had difficulty finding information to solve it. Would you know of any resources?

Comment: So, what that tells you is that your host (or your proxy) is not enabled for websockets, which you really do want for Blazor Server : "Failed to connect Via WebSockets" - You will need to check with your particular host/proxy how to enable websockets

Comment: Thank you, @Mister Magoo and maciek for your help. All I had to do was run the following command in Powershell: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets. I got this from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1BjSRLrIOI